Determining whether there's a permutation that satisfies a linear equation
Given a positive integer $n$ and integer coefficients $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4,..., c_n$, the goal would be to find a $\sigma \in S_n$ ($S_n$ is the group of permutations on $\{1,2,...,N\}$) such that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\sigma(i) = 0$$
Is this problem NP-complete?

It is NP-complete.
It is obviously in NP. We give a reduction from the subset-sum problem to show it is NP-complete.
There are several variants of the subset-sum problem. We use the following one: given $a_1,\ldots,a_n,T$ (they all positive integers), determine whether there exists  a subset of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ with sum $T$. Given such an instance, we construct an instance of your problem as
$$
c_{2k}=b^k+a_k,\ c_{2k+1}=b^k\quad  \text{for}\ k=1,\ldots,n,
$$
and
$$c_1=-\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2kc_{2k}+(2k+1)c_{2k+1}\right)+T\right),$$
where $b$ is a very large number such that

$-2c_1 > (2n+1)\sum_{i=2}^{2n+1}c_i$, and
$b^k>(2n+1)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}b^i+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$.

Note we still need to construct a concrete $b$ satisfying the conditions above for a complete proof, but here we omit this part because it is a bit verbose.
With these conditions, we can see if there exists a permutation $\sigma$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}c_i\sigma(i)=0$, then it must be $\sigma(1)=1$ and $\{\sigma(2k),\sigma(2k+1)\}=\{2k,2k+1\}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. The sum of $a_k$'s with those $k$'s satisfying $\sigma(2k)=2k+1$ and $\sigma(2k+1)=2k$ is exactly $T$.
